# convert request parameter of array hashes to ruby hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following request parameters:

```
"mappings"=>"[{ \"spec_id\" => \"1\",
 \"item_name\" => \"sku\"}|{ \"spec_id\" => \"2\",
 \"item_name\" => \" productname\"}|{ \"spec_id\" => \"4\",
 \"item_name\" => \" price\"}]"
```

I'd like to know how I can parse the items in hashes.

The first thing I do is

```
mappings = params[:mapping][:mappings].split("|")

mappings.each do |map|
   # don't know how to create the hashes
end
```

I would prefer to split on "," instead of "|" if possible and I'm not 100% sure if the request parameter are in the correct format. If it isn't please let me know and I will change it.

Comment: You sure that your string there isn't just the shell output which is params[:mapping][:mappings].inspect?  I doubt you are getting something like that from rails controllers.

Comment: I copied the data from webrick

Comment: If it helps I've managed to change the request parameter to "mappings"=>"[{ 'spec_id' => '1',
 'item_name' => 'sku'}|{ 'spec_id' => '2',
 'item_name' => ' productname'}|{ 'spec_id' => '4',
 'item_name' => ' price'}]"}

Comment: Please keep in mind that the formatting of mappings contents is something I am manually doing myself with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

To parse this string, I would do the following:

```
str = "[{ \"spec_id\" => \"1\",
 \"item_name\" => \"sku\"}|{ \"spec_id\" => \"2\",
 \"item_name\" => \" productname\"}|{ \"spec_id\" => \"4\",
 \"item_name\" => \" price\"}]"

mappings = JSON.parse(str.gsub(/}\s*\|\s*{/, '},{').gsub(/\s*\=\>/, ':'))
```

This will basically convert what you have into a JSON string by removing the '|' characters and converting the '=>' into ':'. When you finally parse the result you'll be parsing JSON, so you'll get a nice Ruby Hash:

```
[{"spec_id"=>"1", "item_name"=>"sku"}, {"spec_id"=>"2", "item_name"=>" productname"}, {"spec_id"=>"4", "item_name"=>" price"}]
```

Comment: The easiest solution was for me to change the request parameter to valid json and then use ActiveSupport::JSON.decode